# What kind of grass is this? It is found in one of zen garden my friend took the picture from

Tags: identification, grass

I love this kind of grass to build my own zen garden. Can anyone help me to identify what kind of grass is this?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like a non-grass groundcover - I think it's irish moss (Sagina subulata). [Here's](http://www.zen-garden.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Sagina-subulata_Irish-Moss.jpg) a photo from a [zen garden site](http://www.zen-garden.org/) showing a similar effect to your photo. You may find the information in the linked site useful in constructing your own garden.

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like a type of moss to me rather than grass. It's so short and dense, like a carpet. Perhaps searching for "Zen garden moss" would give you some ideas for species to grow in your own garden.